# How does no-sql handle relational data?

Tags: java, javascript, sql, nosql

I know it is a non-relational database but this does not mean that relational data does not exist.

For example, I have a table that holds urls like this ( simplified ):

```
url | domain
```

and I have a table that holds domains like this ( simplified ):

```
domain | favicon_path
```

Because many different urls may have the same domain, I did not want to repeat the favicon_path for each domain when pulling the data for sending to the view.

Hence I used a simple ( simplified for example ) join command when I need the data.

```
"SELECT bookmarks.*, domains.favicon FROM bookmarks JOIN 
  domains ON bookmarks.domain=domains.domain"
```

How would I handle this scenario using no-sql?

I plan on implementing no-sql using `indexedDB` on the client ( javascript ) and `MongoDB` on the server ( java ).

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/migrating-from-a-relational-to-a-nosql-cloud-database/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Basic_Concepts_Behind_IndexedDB

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_database

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use document-oriented DB, you can use this structure of documents:

**URL_ID : {
  "domain":"id_of_domain",
  "another_staff": "..."
}**

**DOMAIN_ID : {
   "favicon_path" : "path or id of another document",
   "another_staff": "..."
}**

So you can get document with URL_ID by id from database and then get document of type Domain.

**ADDITION:**
You can use the following approach for generating id. Create special document (like sequence) which will have only one field - current_value_of_sequence. Every insert to DB you have to get this sequence and increment it. Some DB like Couchbase have low-level support of this mechanism, which very efficient and thread-safety.

Comment: what do you mean by "staff" ... is that a synonym for "property"

Comment: Sorry for slang. I meant another fields of your objects, or in terms of Relational database another columns of your table (because documents in document-oriented DB like rows in Relational database).

Comment: can no-sql handle id generation, can it extend off the ids i transfer in from mysql?

Comment: In most cases, transfer between databases making by yourself which, in practice, is not so difficult.

Answer (score 0):

From years of work expierence in IT area, I would say most of the business models could be normalized as simple as these two types of data structure:

1. Entity info.
2. Entity list.

For example, in a book store business, we will have the Book entity, and many list that containing all of the books or a subset of the whole books.

With a NoSQL database, such as [Redis](http://redis.io/) or [SSDB](https://github.com/ideawu/ssdb), the Book entity is stored with Key-Value, where key is the book sn, and value is the stringified book info(title, publish date, description, etc). While book list(list by publish date, list by price, etc) are stored in zset data type.